# Deploy Java Web App Rest Spring Heroku Port Message error R10

Tags: java, hibernate, heroku

I cant deploy my java web app on Heroku, my app use: Java RESTful Web Services with Spring Boot, Jersey and Hibernate...

And i bassed my app from this tutorial : http://jasenkoh.blogspot.cl/2014/09/restfull-web-services-with-spring-boot.html

I have some problem with the PORT, im using the $PORT of the enviroment, as many tutorials says... the most weird thing is that the app works good 1 of 10 times...

Im ussing

This is my procfile:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar target/spring-boot-jersey-      hibernate-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

This is the log:

```
2016-01-18T15:00:10.026560+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-01-18 15:00:10.024  INFO 3 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
2016-01-18T15:00:11.001694+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-01-18 15:00:11.001  INFO 3 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
2016-01-18T15:00:53.762303+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2016-01-18T15:00:10.004813+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-01-18 15:00:10.004  INFO 3 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-01-18T15:00:10.026565+00:00 app[web.1]:    name: default
2016-01-18T15:00:10.026560+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-01-18 15:00:10.024  INFO 3 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
2016-01-18T15:00:10.197117+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-01-18 15:00:10.196  INFO 3 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.7.Final}
2016-01-18T15:00:11.001694+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-01-18 15:00:11.001  INFO 3 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
2016-01-18T15:00:52.906849+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2016-01-18T15:00:10.004813+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-01-18 15:00:10.004  INFO 3 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-01-18T15:00:10.026560+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-01-18 15:00:10.024  INFO 3 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
2016-01-18T15:00:10.197117+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-01-18 15:00:10.196  INFO 3 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.7.Final}
2016-01-18T15:00:52.906849+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2016-01-18T15:00:53.762303+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2016-01-18T15:00:53.773047+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-01-18T15:00:10.004813+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-01-18 15:00:10.004  INFO 3 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-01-18T15:00:10.026560+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-01-18 15:00:10.024  INFO 3 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
2016-01-18T15:00:10.197117+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-01-18 15:00:10.196  INFO 3 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.7.Final}
2016-01-18T15:00:11.001694+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-01-18 15:00:11.001  INFO 3 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
2016-01-18T15:00:52.906849+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2016-01-18T15:00:53.773047+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Error R10 (Boot timeout)` error means that your app is taking more than 60 seconds to start up. It probably works 1 out of 10 times because it manages to start up within that time frame occasionally.

You can try to get your start time down, or ask Heroku Support to increase the limit by opening a ticket at http://help.heroku.com

Comment: Thanks you very much CodeFinger, i will try and then ill let you know!